# Removing Unicode Line Separator "U+2028" in Bash

Tags: bash

I have a [text file](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4619870/output4.txt) with a [unicode line separator](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2028/index.htm) (hex code 2028).

I want to remove it using bash (I see [implementations for Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105106/how-to-exclude-u2028-from-line-separators-in-python-when-reading-file), but not for this language). What command could I use to transform the text file (output4.txt) to lose the unicode line separator?

See in vim below:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably this tr command should also work:

```
tr '\xE2\x80\xA8' ' ' < inFile > outFIle
```

**Working solution:** Thanks to OP for finding this:

```
sed -i.old $'s/\xE2\x80\xA8/ /g' inFile
```

Comment: Alas it doesn't seem to. :/

Comment: Can you try: `tr -d '\x20\x28' < inFile`

Comment: This ended up working: `sed -i.old $'s/\xE2\x80\xA8/ /g' filename` - pretty close to what you had. :)

Comment: Great to know, I edited my answer to reflect that so that future visitors of this page will something useful.

Answer (score 4):

I noticed that in your screenshot, you have already opened file in vim, then why not just do the substitution in vim?

in vim you could do

```
:%s/(seebelow)//g
```

the `(seebelow)` part, you could type:

<kbd>ctrl-v</kbd><kbd>u</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>0</kbd><kbd>2</kbd><kbd>8</kbd>

Comment: I need to automate it, unfortunately - although this is a very helpful tip!

Comment: if you have a few amount file, vim can automatically do it too. (with -w and -s). but if you have a big bunch of files, shell is right way to go.

Answer (score 1):

You can probably use sed:

```
sed 's/\x20\x28//g' <file_in.txt >file_out.txt
```

To overwrite the original file:

```
sed -i 's/\x20\x28//g' file.txt
```

**Edit**: (See chepner's comment) You should make sure that you have the correct bytes, depending on the encoding, and then use sed to delete them. You could use e.g. `od -t x1` for looking at the hex dump and figuring out the encoding.

Comment: 2028 is the Unicode codepoint; how it appears in the file will depend on the encoding. For UTF-8, the byte sequence would be `\xE2\x80\xA8`.

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```sh
sed $'s/\u2028//g' file_in.txt > file_out.txt
```

Note: other questions use the term `<U+2028>`